# German keyboard layout and android studio shortcuts

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio (Version 3.2 and older versions).

I can't use shortcuts like Shift + Slash etc., but the problem is, that i can't edit key shortcuts in the keymap. I can't use keys like Shift or Ctrl in the keymap (other keys like tab,caps lock are working). I tried to do this with an English keyboard layout but this is not working too.

Thank your very much.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "I can't edit key shortcuts in the keymap". Are you getting an error? Did you make a copy of the keymap before editing? Note that you cannot edit the default map. You must first make a copy and edit the copy (and then use the copy).

Comment: No I'm not getting any error... I can use normal keys like "e" or something else in the keymap. Only "ctrl", "shift" and "alt" are not working there... Actually I copied the keymap and edited the xml manually. This is happening on Ubuntu 12.04 and on Windows 8 btw..